# Vue-resource with browserify

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I am trying to use vue-resource with browserify. But I always get the following error. `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. I tried search around the web but the solution is not working.

```
var Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

import UploadImage from './components/UploadImage.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: { UploadImage },

    ready() {
        console.log('Vue is ready.');
        this.$http.get('/api', function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

I install `vue`and `vue-resource` by using npm install.

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
   "devDependencies": {
    "clipboard-js": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-batch-replace": "0.0.0",
    "gulp-phpunit": "^0.14.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vueify": "^1.0.3",
    "vue": "^1.0.24",
    "laravel-elixir-browserify": "^0.8.1",
    "vue-resource": "^0.7.0",
    "vueify": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by updating vue-resource to `v1.x`. Can you do `Vue.http.get(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
ready() {
    Vue.http.get('/api').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestion:

1: Using webpack replace browserify.

2: Using axios replace vue-resource.